# Value labels waterfall

Tags: r

I haven't been able to get the graph I want. I created a waterfall plot with this info:

| name | type | start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GTO | net | 0 | 18283 | 18283 |
| Disc | out | 18283 | 16027 | -2256 |
| Exc | out | 16027 | 12415 | -3612 |
| NR | net | 0 | 12415 | 12415 |
| VIC | out | 12415 | 9551 | -2863 |
| VLC | out | 9551 | 8348 | -1203 |
| MACO | net | 8348 | 0 | 8348 |

```html
<a href='https://postimages.org/' target='_blank'><img src='https://i.postimg.cc/qq77jn9T/MACO-Waterfall.png' border='0' alt='MACO-Waterfall'/></a>
```

However I have not been able to add the value of each column on top. I tried to use geom_text but it gave me an error everytime.

Do you know how can I place the value on top of each column? I appreciate the help!

This is the last code I used, I tried different options but it didn't work so I deleted them.

```
  waterfall_info %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(name, id), fill = type)) +
  geom_rect(aes(x = reorder(name, id), xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start)) +
  geom_text(label = value) +
  labs(title = "MACO Waterfall") + xlab("Measure") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = FALSE)
```

Comment: What code are you trying?

Comment: waterfall_info %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(name, id), fill = type)) +
  geom_rect(aes(x = reorder(name, id), xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, 
                ymin = end, ymax = start)) +
  geom_text(label = value) +
  labs(title = "MACO Waterfall") + xlab("Measure") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = FALSE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For categorical variables, I like using the tile geom so that I can control column width with a single parameter. The downside is that you have to define the center vertical position of the tile (ie halfway between bottom and top) plus its height, which might be less familiar than defining the bottom and top.

To place the text on top, I use `y = pmax(start, end)` but you could just as well use `y = if_else(start > end, start, end)`.

```
library(tidyverse)
waterfall_info %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_inorder(name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, label = scales::comma(value))) + 
  geom_tile(aes(y = (start+end)/2, height = end-start, 
                width = 0.9, fill = type)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pmax(start, end)), vjust = -0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.15))) +
  labs(title = "MACO Waterfall", x = "Measure", y = "value") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(end = 0.6, guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: This plot looks great!

Comment: It looks amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `ggvis` solution:

```
library(ggvis)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(id=row_number())

df1 %>%
    ggvis(x = ~reorder(name, id), y = ~end) %>%
    layer_rects(y2 = ~start, width = band(),
                fill = ~type) %>%
    layer_text(x = prop("x", ~reorder(name, id)),
               y = ~end,
               text := ~value) %>%
    scale_nominal("x", name = "xcenter", padding = 1.2)
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("GTO", "Disc", "Exc", "NR", "VIC", "VLC", 
"MACO"), type = c("net", "out", "out", "net", "out", "out", "net"
), start = c(0L, 18283L, 16027L, 0L, 12415L, 9551L, 8348L), end = c(18283L, 
16027L, 12415L, 12415L, 9551L, 8348L, 0L), value = c(18283L, 
-2256L, -3612L, 12415L, -2863L, -1203L, 8348L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Both diagrams look great! I have to start reviewing `ggplot2` again.